# What are the Ember.js events for TextField Class

Tags: ember.js

Just started to play with Ember.js and by reading the code I encounter the following lines:

```
Em.TextField.extend({
    insertNewline: function() {
        ....
    }
});
```

as far as I understood, `insertNewLine` is an event on clicking "enter" while inside the field, but looking in [the documentation for `TextField`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html) I failed to find information about this event, and other events of `TextField` as well.

What events are supported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a noob question at all!

Ember TextField inherits from Ember's TextSupport. TextSupport is basically a class that can share functionality for text fields (inputs) and text areas.

If you take a look at TextSupport (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_support.js) you'll see a key map at the bottom of the file. This map will be queried on every key up event, trying to match a key to a function. The two default functions are insertNewline (enter) and cancel (esc). You can add as many as you want here.

Answer (score 1):

The keyUp and focusOut methods are also really helpful.  I use them a lot for data validation type purposes on edit forms.

https://github.com/emberjs/website/pull/30